# ¿Por qué en las transacciones fallidas la columna ID se auto-incrementa? ¿Cómo puedo evitarlo?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, transacciones

Tengo la siguiente tabla en MySQL:

```
CREATE TABLE `google_analytics` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `url_path` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `url_title` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ga_views` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `url_path` (`url_path`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3513 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Esta tabla fue llenada de forma masiva mediante la siguiente transacción, usando PDO:

```
    $sql="INSERT INTO google_analytics (url_title, url_path, ga_views) 
          VALUES (:url_title,:url_path,:ga_views)";
    $chk="SELECT COUNT(*) total FROM google_analytics WHERE url_path=:url_path";

    $oPDO->beginTransaction();
    try
    {
        foreach ($rows as $row){
            $arrChk=array('url_path'=>$row[1]);
            $existe=$oPDO->single($chk, $arrChk);

            if ($existe==0){

                $arrParams=array('url_title'=>$row[0], 
                                 'url_path'=>$row[1], 
                                 'ga_views'=>$row[2]);
                $oPDO->query($sql, $arrParams);
            }

        }
        $oPDO->executeTransaction();
        echo "Proceso OK";

    }catch(Exception $e){
        print_r($e);
        $oPDO->rollBack();
    }
}
```

El hecho es que en la creación del script de la transacción el código falló varias veces (sobre todo por violación de clave duplicada en el `INSERT`), hasta que pude refinarlo y hacer que la inserción fuera efectiva.

El problema es que **todas las veces que falló la columna `id`  de mi tabla se auto-incrementó por cada posible fila.**

Ahora mi tabla está así (del id `3` pasa al `2682`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

### Mi pregunta

- **¿Por qué en mi transacción se incrementó la columna `id`?** Yo tenía entendido que en las transacciones la BD no era afectada cuando había un fallo.
- **¿Hay alguna forma de evitar que se auto-incremente en futuras transacciones que puedan fallar?**

**NOTA:** No pregunto sobre cómo regularizar la columna `id`, sino sobre por qué se auto-incrementó en transacciones fallidas.

Comment: Gracias @Marcos entiendo lo que dices. Entonces estaba errado en mi forma de entender las transacciones. Yo entendía que nada cambiaba hasta que no se hacía el `commit`. Efectivamente, lo que hace `rollBack` es deshacer los cambios que ya se han hecho. Agradecería una respuesta de tu parte si es posible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Según el manual de `MySQL` [las transacciones](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/glossary.html#glos_transaction) son:

> unidades de trabajo atómicas que pueden comprometerse o retrotraerse. Cuando una transacción realiza múltiples cambios en la base de datos, todos los cambios tienen éxito cuando se confirma la transacción (`commited`), o todos los cambios se deshacen cuando se revierte la transacción (`rolled back`).
>
> Las transacciones de base de datos, implementadas por `InnoDB`, tienen propiedades que se conocen colectivamente con el acrónimo **`ACID`**, por atomicidad, consistencia, aislamiento y durabilidad.

Al iniciar una transacción, **toda acción se realiza físicamente sobre las tablas** (*no es una simulación*).

Cuando la acción es una modificación (`UPDATE`) o eliminación (`DELETE`) y luego se retrotrae (`roll back`), `InnoDB` restaura el estado original de los datos. Los datos originales son almacenados en un área de la base de datos llamada segmento de retrotracción ([`rollback segment`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/glossary.html#glos_rollback_segment)).

Durante una transacción, todos los registros que son creados, modificados o eliminados son marcados con un [`transaction ID`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/glossary.html#glos_transaction_id), el cual es utilizado para retrotraer dicha transacción.

---

Ahora, respecto a tus preguntas:

> ¿Por qué en mi transacción se incrementó la columna id?

Al realizar un `INSERT` el registro es realmente insertado, es por esto que el indice `AUTO INCREMENT` es incrementado.

> ¿Hay alguna forma de evitar que se auto-incremente en futuras transacciones que puedan fallar?

Si consideramos que normalmente un registro con un indice `auto-increment` es utilizado como clave primaria ([`primary key`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/glossary.html#glos_primary_key)) y que este `ID` puede ser usado para relacionarlo a otros registros en la misma tabla u otras, por ejemplo como una clave foranea ([`foreign key`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/glossary.html#glos_foreign_key)), el tratar de evitar el incremento automático de dicho indice seguramente conlleve un esfuerzo innecesario y propenso a errores, como por ejemplo, la capacidad de ejecutar múltiples operaciones simultáneamente ([`concurrency`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/glossary.html#glos_concurrency))